# Calculate the intersection point of $m$ with $AC$.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be the triangle with $A=(0,0)$, $B=(16,0)$ and $C=(4,16)$.

Let $B'$ be the midpoint of the side $\overline{AC}$, let $C'$ be the midpoint of the side $\overline{AB}$ and let $I$ be the point $(2\sqrt{17}-2, 9-\sqrt{17})$.

1. Calculate the line that goes through $B$ and $I$.
2. The angle bisector $m$ at $B$ of the triangle $ABC$ divides the opposite $\overline{AC}$ proportional to the adjacent sides. Calculate the intersection point of $m$ with $AC$. Show that this intersection point is on the line $BI$.
3. Show that $I$ has the same distance to $AB$ as to $AC$.
4. Conclude that $I$ is the center of the inscribed circle of the triangle $ABC$and calculate the line that goes through $I$ and the contact point of the inscribed circle and the side $\overline{BC}$.

$$$$

For **question 1** we have:

\begin{equation*}y-0=\frac{9-\sqrt{17}-0}{2\sqrt{17}-2-16}(x-16)  \Rightarrow y=-\frac{1}{2}(x-16) \end{equation*}

For **question 2** we have:

We have to calculate the side lengths $|AB|$ and $|BC|$, right?

We have that $|AB|=16$ and $|BC|=\sqrt{12^2+16^2}=20$. Therefore $m$ divides the side $\overline{AC}$ in relation $\frac{20}{16}=\frac{5}{4}$, right? But how can we calculate the coordinates of that point?

For **question 3** we have:

Here we just use the formula for distances and calculate both and see that these are equal, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do for part (2) is to compute the intersection point of the line you got from part (1), with the line that passes through $A$ and $C$, which you have not yet calculated.  This is simply $$y = \frac{16}{4} x = 4x,$$ consequently the intersection point, which we will call $P$, satisfies the system $$\begin{align} y &= -\frac{x}{2} + 8 \\ y &= 4x. \end{align}$$  Then compute the distances $|PA|$ and $|PC|$, and show that because $$\frac{|PA|}{|AB|} = \frac{|PC|}{|CB|},$$ point $P$ obeys the proportionality criterion, thus $P$ lies on the angle bisector of $\angle B$.  Conclude that, since this line is also the line passing through $BI$ from part (1), that $I$ lies on the angle bisector of $\angle B$.

For part (3), simply perform the distance calculation.  The distance of $I$ to $AB$ is easy.  However, the distance of $I$ to $AC$ requires us to find the line perpendicular to $AC$ passing through $I$, computing its intersection point $Q$ with $AC$, then computing the distance $|QI|$.

For part (4), observe from parts (2) and (3) that if $I$ lies on the angle bisector of $\angle B$, then the distance of $I$ to $BC$ equals the distance of $I$ to $AB$; therefore, $I$ is equidistant to all three sides of $\triangle ABC$, hence $I$ is the incenter.

Comment: As for part (3), couldn't we just use the formula $\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ ?

Comment: As for part (4) to calculate the contact point of the inscribed circle and the side $\overline{BC}$ we have to calculate first theequation of the circle, which has center $I$ and radius $d(I,BC)=d(I,AB)=d(I,AC)$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar The purpose of part (2) is to show that $I$ lies on the angle bisector. You can do this two ways: one is to locate the point $P$ on $AC$ that satisfies the proportionality condition (thus is on the bisector), then show $I$ is collinear with $PB$ because the equation for line $IB$ passes through $P$.  The other way is to do what I suggested in the answer, which is to find the intersection of $IB$ with $AC$, call this $P$, and then show that the proportionality condition $|PA|/|AB| = |PC|/|CB|$ is true by calculating the distances.

Comment: For part (3), yes you absolutely can.  In fact, the formula you cite can be derived by the process I described in my solution.  Since I did not know that you were aware of this formula, I did not assume you knew to use it, and instead described an approach using first principles.

Comment: As for part (4), your proposal is unnecessary.  The reason is because in part (2), you showed that $I$ lies on the angle bisector of $\angle B$, therefore the distance from $I$ to side $AB$ is the same as the distance from $I$ to side $BC$.  In other words, my explanation in part (4) is more or less a complete proof in itself.  No additional calculation is required.

Comment: As for part (2) : So we find the intersection point of $IB$ and $AC$ and call it $P$ and show that this is on the bisector angle. Since $P$ is also on $BI$ the points $P$ and $I$ are on the same line, i.e. the bisector angle of $B$. Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: Yes, I understood your part (4) of the answer, it was very clear to me!! I am asking about the second part of question (4) "calculate the line that goes through $I$ and the contact point of the inscribed circle and the side $\overline{BC}$". It is radius of that inscribed circle,right? But to calculate that line do we have to calculate first the equation of the circle? Or is the line that we are looking for perpendicular to $\overline{BC}$ and goes through $I$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar For part (2), that is precisely correct.  For part (4), the key idea is that the distance from a point $I$ to a line $m$ is equal to the radius of a circle whose center is $I$ and is tangent to $m$.  So if you can show that $I$ is equidistant from lines $AB$ and $BC$, then the circle with center at $I$ and radius equal to this common distance is tangent to $AB$ and $BC$.  You do not need to calculate an equation for the circle.

Comment: I got stuck right now. So what is meant to do at the question "calculate the line that goes through I and the contact point of the inscribed circle and the side $\overline{BC}$ " ?

Comment: @MaryStar I apologize, I forgot about that part of the question.  All it is asking you to do is compute the equation of the line through $I$ and the point of tangency of the incircle to $BC$.  One way to get the point of tangency is to calculate the equation of line $BC$, then for a point $R = (x,y)$ on $BC$, find the value of $(x,y)$ such that $|RI|$ is the inradius.  Or you can reflect the point $(2 \sqrt{17} - 2, 0)$ about the line $BI$, if you know such a formula.  Or you can solve the system of equations for the incircle $I$ and the line $BC$.  There are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: Ok! I will try the first way...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! :-)